# xmlHttpRequest abort() method does not close the connection in Internet Explorer

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, abort

I have multiple `xmlHttpRequest` on my page, and I am attempting to call the `abort()` method on them all. Works great in FF. IE, on the other hand does not do a darn thing. The connections do not close, and I am unable to navigate to another page until the requests complete. What is this? Why doesn't IE close the connections when `abort()` is called?

Answer (score 2):

I've almost never gotten abort to work in IE.  I'm tired and can't remember why - something about not being able to abort until you're in readyState 4 (or maybe that it changed to readyState 4 when it aborts?).  Either way, Ajaxian has a work around in the depths of its' archives:

http://ajaxian.com/archives/reusing-xmlhttprequest-without-abort

Answer (score 0):

### Parallel-Ajax requests vs Apache-Session locking

---

**Session data** is usually **stored after** your **script terminated**, but as *session data is locked to prevent concurrent writes* **only one script may operate on a session at any time**.

When e.g. using framesets together with sessions you will experience the frames loading one by one due to this locking. **You can reduce the time** needed to load all the frames **by ending the session as soon as possible**.

---

So you can use sessions in ajax scripts with
`session_start();` (maybe handled automatically) followed immediately (soon as possible) by `session_write_close();`

`session_write_close();` will "end" the current session and store the session data.

*But:* `session_id()` will still deliver the correct (current) PHPSESSID so you're able to re obtain write access to the current session by simply doing `session_start()` again at any time you need it.

---

I use it this way in all my ajax scripts to implement session handling *and* allowing parallel request (with aborting) in all browsers