# IE11 SSE via Polyfill never terminate connections?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, server-sent-events, polyfills

I have been playing around with Server-Sent Events and the equivalent Polyfill for IE and things work great with one glaring exception.  When I close the tab/browser or reload the page, the connection between the client and server remains open indefinitely since my sample SSE server pushes content every 5 seconds.  What's worse, is I can hit reload and get a new connection each time, which is a potential avenue to DOS-attacking the webserver since I can create a large number of connections that never appear to close.  Browsers that natively support SSE or even those that rely on the polyfill (with the exception of IE) don't exhibit this behavior.

The sample server I'm using is:
https://github.com/kljensen/golang-html5-sse-example/blob/master/server.go

Which serves this webpage:
https://github.com/kljensen/golang-html5-sse-example/blob/master/templates/index.html

And I have added the following polyfill:
https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource/blob/master/eventsource.js

I get the same behavior with a number of other polyfills and server implementations.  I can wireshark the traffic and see the server's TCP connection continuing to send data and get ACKS back from the client long after IE has been closed (at least 10-30 minutes, likely longer).  From debugging IE, it seems that calls to `xhr.abort()` never actually abort/close the connection.

I have seen similar complains about xhr abort in IE in questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377473/xmlhttprequest-abort-method-does-not-close-the-connection-in-internet-explorer)

I am curious if anyone else has had this issue.  From researching SSE, just about all of the sources say you can use a polyfill for IE/non-supported browsers and things work great, but this seems like a pretty serious shortcoming and I am surprised that there doesn't seem to be any information on this specific issue.