# Is there Canceled status at all for XHR requests made in IE and Edge?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, rxjs, microsoft-edge

Here is a sample JavaScript code which is aborting a long-running call after 1 second (the test endpoint got 3 seconds sleep in it)

```
function reqListener() {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET", 'https://localhost:5001/api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts?cachebuster=' + new Date().getTime(), true);
oReq.send();

setTimeout(function () {
  oReq.abort();
}, 1000);
```

XMLHttpRequest.abort() works as expected in Chrome, showing that the request is Canceled in the DevTools:
[image]

However, when it's running in IE10/11/Edge, the result is confusing:
[image]

It just sits in the Pending status forever. I wonder is it me doing something wrong, or is it just the way IE is showing canceled requests? If latter, it looks more like an IE bug to me tbh...

I double checked that without abort(), the call is returning result in the reqListener() function as expected. I.e. the server is definitely not stuck.

NB: the same thing happens when RxJS is used with unsubscribing from the network call observable in timer. I didn't try jQuery, but I presume the result gonna be the same.

NB2: The [8 yrs old issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377473/xmlhttprequest-abort-method-does-not-close-the-connection-in-internet-explorer) is a) too old, and b) about abort() doing nothing in old IE, while my question is that nowadays abort() is effectively aborting connection... but in a suspicious way, suggesting that a connection might be leaking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xmlHttpRequest abort() method does not close the connection in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377473/xmlhttprequest-abort-method-does-not-close-the-connection-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen hmmm thanks but not quite - the post from 8 yrs ago says that "IE, on the other hand does not do a darn thing" - these days it certainly does a thing. In IE10/11/Edge, the JS code is not getting the response, so effectively IE cancels it. I just would like to confirm that it is the actual "canceled connection" rather than a "leaked connection".

Comment: I had an issue with just Edge requests being left in "(Pending)" and it turned out we had "Zero-width space" in our IIS HTTP Response Header.

Comment: @InphinitePhractals thanks for the suggestion! Maybe IIS was the reason yes. It's an old question, and from what I remember the server handler thread was just paused for a few seconds in my test case. So there probably were no headers from the server by the time of abort(). But thanks anyway! Looking at IIS there might be a good lead.

Comment: @Mikha Ah, okay.  It's a lead at least, and I thought I'd pass on a possible solution for anyone else that might across something similar to this.